# FireBase Google

Tags: android, servidor, google, firebase

Atualmente eu utilizo o Firebase database da Google, ( e outros componentes como, auth, FCM, etc) para o meu projeto. Gostaria de saber se há como criar rotinas no lado do servidor. Por exemplo: depois de um período de dias a rotina busca pelos usuários de acordo com uma regra de negócio e envia notificações, tudo feito através da rotina. Há algo assim disponibilizado pelo Firebase ?

Comment: Este fórum é em português, você pode perguntar em português ou usar o Stack Overflow em inglês. Leia isso: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Pergunta corrigida, obrigado !

Comment: -1 removido, após a correção.

Comment: Acredito que não, já tentei uma época atrás e não tinha como, só se implementaram isto agora.

Answer (score 2):

Se a dúvida ainda persistir para alguém, a Google disponibiliza criação de crons utilizando o Cloud Functions (Firebase).

Alguns links que explicam o funcionamento do mesmo:

http://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/how-to-schedule-cron-jobs-with-cloud.html

https://github.com/firebase/functions-cron

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar suas rotinas no lado servidor usando **Firebase Database REST API** e mandar suas notificações via **curl** também. Basta criar de acordo com sua regra de negocio

[Firebase Database REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/)

Comment: Eu li sobre, você sabe se tem como eu deixar um "motor sempre ligado" do lado do servidor que realiza rotinas sozinhas ? Acho que esse era o ponto em que queria chegar.

Comment: Tem sim. você pode usar um cron para agendar sua tarefa e executar seu script no servidor da uma olhada: http://www.infowester.com/linuxcron.php

Comment: De qualquer forma eu teria que ter o meu próprio servidor para fazer os agendamentos das tarefas ? **Firebase** não oferece tal serviço ?

Comment: Sim eu pelo menos faço assim. Nesse caso não sei se o Database do firebase possui esse serviço, mas o Notification sim você pode agendar quando mandar a notificação